# Java OpenCSV How to edit specific cells from csv file

Tags: java, opencsv

I have a CSV file which looks like this:
http://gyazo.com/5dcfb8eca4e133cbeac87f514099e320.png

I need to figure out how I can read specific cells and update them in the file.

This is the code I am using:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.opencsv.*;

public class ReadCSV {

    private static final char SEPARATOR = ';';

    public static void updateCSV(String input, String output, String  replace, int row, int col) throws IOException {   

          CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(input),SEPARATOR);
            List<String[]> csvBody = reader.readAll();
            csvBody.get(row)[col]=replace;
            reader.close();

            CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(output),SEPARATOR,' ');
            writer.writeAll(csvBody);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String source = "townhall_levels.csv";
        String destiantion="output.csv";
        ReadCSV.updateCSV(source, destiantion, "lol", 1, 1);

    }

}
```

In this code I am just trying to change A1 to "lol" as an example test to see if it works but I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at ReadCSV.updateCSV(ReadCSV.java:16)
    at ReadCSV.main(ReadCSV.java:30)
```

How should I go about achieving my goal and fixing the error?

CSV File: www.forumalliance.net/townhall_levels.csv

Comment: Post your csv file as text, not as a link to an image. We need to see what is actually in the file. You should also learn to debug by yourself: print each array of the body, or use your debugger to see what it contains.

Comment: @JBNizet posted CSV file

Comment: The file content itself should be **in the question**. Not as a URL.

Comment: @JBNizet doesn't format properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `;`as the separator to parse the file. Your file uses `,`. Also, using a space as the quote char doesn't make much sense. You should use `"` instead, since that's also what your file uses.

Answer (score 0):

The first values you're passing to row and col are 1 and 1. However, these need to start at 0.

Comment: thanks, that doesn't seem to have worked entirely though: http://gyazo.com/a7aedf1112615d5c951c0acb5aae7480

Comment: You should debug your code to see that you're actually getting values that you expect. If you're not comfortable using a debugger (which I would recommend), even some System.out.println() statements will help you see what the problem might be